# assign characters to elements of an array which isnt of the int, string, double, etc. class

Tags: java

So I have a method that reads a file and assigns classes to elements of an array. How do I assign a special character for each class that I am giving to my array?

The array is of the class "Element" that has 3 attributes (`int`, `int`, `char`)
and those classes (Fantasma, which is a subclass of "Element").

```
public void ReadFile() throws FileNotFoundException
{    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("inicio.txt"));
    while (scan.hasNext())
    {
        String line = scan.next();

        if (line.equals("Pared"))
        {
            int i = scan.nextInt();
            int j = scan.nextInt();

            _mundo = new Pared[i][j];
        }

        else if (line.equals("Fantasma"))
        {
            int i = scan.nextInt();
            int j = scan.nextInt();

            _mundo = new Fantasma[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little clearer on what you are doing?   What I read was that you were trying to add objects to an array but in looking at your code, I may be wrong.  To me it looks like you are trying to call Pared and Fantasma constructors  but you are using syntax that indicates they are arrays.

Comment: yes, im trying to add objects to my array, but i really dont know how to do it, and then im trying to show any character in that specific position of the array i added a object.

Comment: Can you give me a little help

Comment: Can I assume _mundo is your array and that i and j represent the position in the array where you want to place your new Pared or Fantasma?

Comment: yes, you are assuming right. and the lines that says  (_mundo = new Fantasma[i][j]) or Pared, are wrong as you said. i think it should be (_mundo[i][j] = new Pared(i, j) am i right? Pared and Fantasma has 2 atributes (int, int)

Comment: sorry for being unspecific, i am new with java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not good style to update global variables like your `_mundo`. You should have your method return an array.

I'm not sure why you would want to duplicate the i / j information as locations in your array *and* as arguments to your element constructor. It would make more sense to do something like this:

```
// untested!
abstract class Element {
    private char character;
    public char getChar() {
        return character;
    }
    Element(char c) {
        character = c;
    }
}

class Fantasma extends Element {
    Fantasma() {
        super('F');
    }
}

class Pared extends Element {
    Pared() {
        super('P');
    }
}

class Vacio extends Element {
    Vacio() {
        super(' ');
    }
}

public Element[][] readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("inicio.txt"));
    Element[][] res = new Element[10][10]; // insert your dimensions here
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        String line = scan.next();
        if (line.equals("Pared") || line.equals("Fantasma")) {
            int i = scan.nextInt();
            int j = scan.nextInt();
            if(line.equals("Pared"))
                res[i][j] = new Pared();
            else
                res[i][j] = new Fantasma();
        }
    }
    // add spaces so we're not left with any null references
    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < res[i].length; j++)
            if (res[i][j] == null)
                res[i][j] = new Vacio();
    return res;
}
```

Then you can for example print it out with

```
Element[][] grid = readFile();
for (Element[] ea : grid) {
    for (Element e : ea)
         System.out.print(e.getChar());
     System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: thanks!, let me see if i cant get it to work. but i have a couple of question, i assume the getChat method it's an abstract method right? and what does the ":" stands for?

Comment: Thanks you very much Luigi, it was of great use your answer, i got to run my program as i wanted. apreciated

Comment: you're welcome. `getChar()` is not abstract - it's just on an abstract class, and is inherited by subclasses. The `:` is syntax for the "enhanced-for loop" (look it up) and is pronounced "in".